# Equivalent Grothendieck toposes

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

Let $(\mathbb{C}, J)$ and $(\mathbb{D}, K)$ be small sites whose associated Grothendieck toposes are equivalent: $\mathsf{Sh}(\mathbb{C}, J) \simeq \mathsf{Sh}(\mathbb{D}, K)$. I am aware that a given Grothendieck topos can have many "inequivalent" sites of definition, but is there any relation between the sites $(\mathbb{C}, J)$ and $(\mathbb{D}, K)$ that can be deduced from the associated Grothendieck toposes being equivalent?

Comment: Well, at worst there is a third site connecting the two given sites by morphisms of sites, realising the given equivalence of toposes. Is that the kind of answer you are looking for?

Comment: If you already have a morphism of sites and are wondering whether it induces an equivalence of toposes, then Olivia Caramello has good news for you, since the recently found an if-and-only-if condition characterizing this situation :-) (https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.08737)

Answer (score 2):

In general that is a very difficult question, and as far as I know there isn't yet a site characterization for the resulting topoi to be equivalent.

However, restricting to certain classes of topoi and sites there do exist characterizations.  Just to give a flavour of this:

1. If $X$, $Y$ are sober spaces, they can be recovered from their topoi $Sh(X)$ and $Sh(Y)$ and so $Sh(X) \simeq Sh(Y)$ iff $X \cong Y$.  More generally, if $L$, $K$ are distributive lattices then $Sh(L,J_{can}) \simeq Sh(K, J_{can})$ iff $K$ and $L$ have isomorphic co-completions.
2. If the topoi are presheaf topoi, then $Sets^{\mathcal{C}^{op}} \simeq Sets^{\mathcal{D}^{op}}$ iff $Ind(\mathcal{C}) \cong Ind(\mathcal{D})$ (the [Ind-completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ind-completion)).
3. Theorem 3 from [this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1988-310-02/S0002-9947-1988-0973173-9/S0002-9947-1988-0973173-9.pdf) by Moerdijk gives sufficient conditions for the topoi of sheaves on two topological groupoids to be equivalent.
4. Corollary 6.6 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.10277.pdf) characterizes equivalence between presheaves on monoids algebraically.